# Disable country field in checkout Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, xml, fieldsets

I tried to disable the `country field` in checkout but i can't.

I already disable few fields like `company` on checkout  page by adding this this

`<item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>` code in  `module_checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml.`

```
<item name="company" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">0</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

If i try to do the same thing for country filed, this field dosen't disappear.

Does anyone know if it's any other solution for disable this field?

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html#disable-a-component

Comment: i already add <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item> for disable the filed, and it's not working.

Comment: Did You add `<item name="componentDisabled"`?

Comment: there are 2 country filed in checkout_index_index.xml     <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id]]></item>
                                                                        <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
                                                                        </item>  and     this one  <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                </item>

Comment: in which one i need to add this line <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>?

Answer (score 1):

First select default country from admin then, using css

```
 div[name="shippingAddress.country_id"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should disappear by following:

```
<item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
</item>
```

Comment: using this way region/state filed also get hidden. But state field required here and country fields should be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Solved it with this code:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.shipping">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-summary" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="block-shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="address-fieldsets" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Comment: Do let me know if you face any issue.